# 5mg tablet (finasteride) and 2mg finasteride tablet

Tags: hair, hairloss

i am taking finasteride 1mg table, but these days, 1mg table not available. So i am taking 5mg tablet and make it half and taking it. So is that okay ?

Comment: This is something you should either discuss with your doctor or pharmacist. You could also try to perhaps get a 2mg tablet and cut that in half. However, if the tablets are supposed to be some kind of extended release, cutting them in half is not the best idea.